# How to update object in firebase I tried doing this but it executes multiple times?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have retrieved the object form database then I update it by method `addreport()` then I save it again

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
  .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Empinfo q = dataSnapshot.getValue(Empinfo.class);
        q.addreport(s);
        dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(q);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), profileImageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some logs? what message do you get when you hit `addreport` ?

Comment: If you want to **update** a specific value, you can use [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E,%20com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.CompletionListener)). There's a nice explanation to this problem, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener()`. You have implemented a continuous listener on a ref. Here is what is happening...

Step 1: Adding listener to a ref and getting the data. This listener is continuously listening for changes on this ref.

Step 2: Convert data into object and perform operations(your logic)

Step 3: Save data to firebase. Now that you have changed the data your onDataChanged will be called again.

Step 4: But this time your object is already updated so adding `q.addreport(s);` will have no change in object.

Step 5: You try to save the data in firebase but there are no changes to be saved so it will terminate.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
  .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Empinfo q = dataSnapshot.getValue(Empinfo.class);
        q.addreport(s);
        dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(q);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), profileImageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

I used `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, which fetches the data but does not do live updates instead of `addValueEventListener` which does live updates for every data change.
Your problem is potentially caused by using the instruction `dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(q);` inside the `onDataChange` method of an `addValueEventListener` call so there was a recursion in that section.